# After tried all solutions, EJS still failed to lookup view "index.ejs" in views directory

Tags: node.js

I'm a seasoned programmer learning MEAN stack. Got this err during practice, "

> Failed to lookup view 'full path' in views directory 'physical path'.

I thought path is not a complicated thing, surprisingly AFTER search and tried many solutions for the similar err here still not being able to resolve it. Here is my base code of server.js, pay attention to **res.render**

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
...
app.get('/quotes', (req, res)=>
{    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html'); })    // running ok
// post-to (Create)
app.post('/quotes', (req, res) => 
{
    ...
    {
        res.redirect('/');
    })
})

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.get('/', (req, res)=>
{
    ...
    {
        res.render('index.ejs', ...);  
    })
})
```

**Here are what I tried and results**:

```
// -- 1) original
res.render('index.ejs', ...);
```

Failed to lookup view "index.ejs" in views directory "C:\Node.project\views"

---

```
// -- 2) set path explicitly ahead of "view engine" using path.join()
var path = require('path');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
res.render('index.ejs', ...);
```

Failed to lookup view "index.ejs" in views directory "C:\Node.project\mean1\views"

---

```
// -- 3) concat, __dirname + '/views'
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
res.render('index.ejs', ...);
```

Failed to lookup view "index.ejs" in views directory "C:\Node.project\mean1/views"

---

```
// -- 4) reverse "/" to "\"
app.set('views', __dirname + '\views');
res.render('index.ejs', ...);
```

Failed to lookup view "index.ejs" in views directory "C:\Node.project\mean1iews"

---

```
// -- 5) w/o setting default "views", simply tell where to look for the template
res.render(__dirname + '/MEAN1/views/index.ejs', ...);
```

Failed to lookup view "C:\Node.project\mean1/views/index.ejs" in views directory "C:\Node.project\views"

My guess is it has something to do with the structure

```
\Node.project (folder)
  |-- package.js, package.json (files)
  |
  \MEAN1 (folder)
      |-- index.html, server.js (files)
      |
      \views (folder)
          |-- index.ejs
```

How do I start node? Either Nodemon or Node, that is
at Node.project folder,

> "nodemon MEAN1/server.js"

Or, at MEAN1 folder,

> "node server.js"

.

Comment: EJS uses the ./views folder relative to root by default. Try this: https://scotch.io/tutorials/use-ejs-to-template-your-node-application. You can also omit the .ejs extension. I'd recommend setting the basic usage up so you can establish a baseline and see it functional, and then begin optimizing your structure.

Comment: I can't see exactly what the problem is given this set of data here, but I think you are close. I also see an opportunity to mention that Express can be sensitive to the order you load the middlewares with respect to things using them. I would put the `app.use()` stuff above all your routes.

Comment: @agm1984 Thanks for the comment, checking on it now...

Comment: @agm1984 made a copy of index.ejs to xx.ejs, and used that xx.ejs works.

Answer (score 0):

To my biggest surprise after read and tried many diff ways, simply copied the index.ejs as XX.ejs, in server.js replaced "index" with "XX", Hooray!
Still not sure what's the cause. 
I saw a few same err while location and file are all there w/o proper reason. It may suggest Express is the culprit.
Posted here to help others avoid wasting time when having the same unexplainable issue.